# Working with Bluefieldscom intl-tel-input, how can I make the flag dropdown not overlap with other inputs?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, intl-tel-input

[image: screenshot here]

As you can see from the screenshot, I have 3 inputs and when I click the first one, the flags for the 2nd and 3rd input will be on top of the 1st dropdown's list.

How can I make this dropdown to be "on top" or make the other stay in the background?

Below is the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/DtMwr/

```
$(function() {
    $("#p1").intlTelInput({
        preferredCountries:['US', 'CA', 'AU', 'BR', 'SG', 'DE', 'NL', 'RU', 'IE'],
        americaMode: false
    });
    $("#p2").intlTelInput({
        preferredCountries:['US', 'CA', 'AU', 'BR', 'SG', 'DE', 'NL', 'RU', 'IE'],
        americaMode: false
    });
    $("#p3").intlTelInput({
        preferredCountries:['US', 'CA', 'AU', 'BR', 'SG', 'DE', 'NL', 'RU', 'IE'],
        americaMode: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Without access to your code or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), all I can tell you is that it appears to be a z-index issue.

Comment: @BrianRay http://jsfiddle.net/DtMwr/ here is the fiddle, im unable to get the images working, but you can see similar issue with the flag dropdown in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed caused by a z-index issue.

I was looking at the z-index of the wrong element(the ul).

Below is the code I used to fix my issue:

```
var z = 1000;
$.each($(".intl-tel-input"), function() {
    this.style.zIndex = z;
    z--;
});
```

.intl-tel-input is the new div that is created when the dropdown input was created.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use css?

Example:

```
.intl-tel-input{
z-index: 1000 !important; //!important overrides the inline-value
}
```